# Unable to Get SP List Due with Additional Parameter in Url

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, powershell

I am able to retrieve the `List` name of a document library with the following `Document Library`:

```
http://test.com/RecordsDocument/
```

However, I encountered the following error for the following `List`:

```
http://test.com/Lists/FilePlan
```

The difference is the additional `/Lists/` component in the 2nd URL.

Below is my code snippet, may I know how can I tackle this issue?

```
$baseUrl="http://test.com/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl

$RDlistName ="RecordsDocument"    //success
$FPlistName ="Lists/FilePlan"     //failed
//$FPlistName ="FilePlan"         //failed

$RDlist = $web.Lists[$RDlistName] //success
$FPlist = $web.Lists[$FPlistName] //empty value

Write-host List Name: $RDlist     //success
Write-host List Name: $FPlist     //empty value
```

Comment: try with the display name of the "FilePlan" list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the PowerShell command below:

```
$baseUrl="http://spsite/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
$FPlistName ="ListName"
$FPlist = $web.Lists[$FPlistName]
Write-host List Name: $FPlist.Title
```

Check if it return data.
If the issue exists, use the PowerShell command to return all lists and libraries in this web, check if the list exists.

```
$baseUrl="http://spsite/"
$web = Get-SPWeb $baseUrl
foreach($list in $web.lists){ 
 write-host $list.Title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using url of your list that never change.
Your list title can be changed

```
$webUrl = "http://mySiteUrl"

$listUrl = "/lists/myList"

$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue;
if($web -eq $null)
{
     read-Host "cannot access to $($webUrl) push any key to exit"
     exit 0;
}
Write-Host "connected to $($webUrl) Title $($web.Title)"

$list = $web.GetList([Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::ConcatUrls($web.ServerRelativeUrl, $listUrl));
```